# Delphi-XE5, Data.DBXMySQL Cannot resolve Unit Name

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have an application I developed for PC using the TsqlConnection Component The driver is set to MySQL and runs great when the driver dll's are present. I wanted to make a client for Android Using Delphi XE5. I again used TsqlConnection and when I select mySql for the Driver property it adds Data.DBXMySQL To my USES section but the compiler tells me "Cannot Resolve Unit Name"... Is this .pas not in delphi's library, or am I missing something else? Also I'm fairly certain that I'll need some kind of lib file like the DLL's I used in my pc application. Please do not suggest I use another component (that won't solve my issue or better my understanding) thanks!

Comment: It's not supported for Android. A simple search could have concluded that, such as this: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.dbexpress/-dcc-fatal-error-unit2.pas-7-f10/1081261 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBlodeG1euU

Comment: @ Jerry Dodge, In the component pallet if you hover over the dbx component it lists "Supported Platforms" Android is listed...

Comment: The package it came installed with supports Android, but that particular component does not. Read the link I gave you. There are no MySQL drivers for Android.